# Require Formula - If Even Possible

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm writing a system tool written in Java which essentially, starts a task at t0 and completes in N secs. Because I anticipate this tool to run on different machines, the time to perform a task will vary.

So, before this tool starts, it needs to do a one-off calibration so that it can accurately predict how long tasks will take to complete ("accurate" as in 1 to 3 secs is fine).

Basically I have measurements for x and y, which completes in N seconds...

```
x                       y                           N Seconds
------------------------------------------------------------
1.0                     15                          5.54
1.5                     15                          3.64
2.0                     15                          2.73

1.0                     35                          12.7
1.5                     35                          8.44
2.0                     35                          6.23

1.0                     55                          19.9
1.5                     55                          13.8
2.0                     55                          10.3
```

Given the measurements above, can I derive a magic formula which says, "if a task is to complete in 15 seconds, then x has to be "blah" and y is "blah".

Obviously math isn't my strong point, is a formula even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't make sense of your table.  What are x and y?  Are they two machines with different timing?  Are they parameters that result in taking N seconds?  I'm sure that the table is clear to you, but I'm not you and don't understand it.

Comment: @btilly Why do you care? The mening is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: The meaning is far from irrelevant.  If I knew what they meant then I could see how well the data fit a reasonable equation, and sanity check that the equation made sense.  Without context I'm not even sure what is being asked, or what data is being offered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From playing around with the data in the question, it looks like this function is a fairly good approximation.

```
z = y / (x * 2.67)
```

For example, for x = 1.5, and y = 15, it gives 3.74, and for x = 1.0 and y = 55, it gives 20.6.

You have two free parameters, so if you want say, z = 15, then you can just substitute and get an estimate for y or x.  Without knowing one, you can't really know the other.

```
15 = y / (x * 2.67)
15 / (x * 2.67) = y
y = 5.83 / x
x = 5.83 / y
```

Comment: thank you @rrenaud, this is brilliant, and is **exactly** what I was after..thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the values in the table, simply use that table. If you need more, you have to use some function interpolation method to get the formula, for exapmple [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

> if a task is to complete in 15
>   seconds, then x has to be "blah" and y
>   is "blah"

There can possibly infinte solutions for the above. But it would make senses to find a x, given y and N.

1. Basically you want to find [correlation](http://psychology.about.com/od/researchmethods/ss/expdesintro_5.htm) between x,y and N. There are many algorithms to determine linear correlation like [Linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).
2. Unless you are running in fundamentally different machines like one machine is a client WInXP and another a Linux Box, I dont think you need to dwell this deep, because chances are other small things can overcome the timings(for e.g. other processes running on system)

Comment: _Basically you want to find correlation between x and y._ That is not what (s)he is asking for! Read the question more carefully.